# How do you find the equivalent voltage of the current source in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source

The circuit is shown at this schematic.

[image]

How do I find the equivalent voltage of the current source by simplifying the circuit?

Comment: No, i originally intended to put this circuit up but when I put it up in that question, I drew it wrong and people assumed that it was a short-circuit at R3

Comment: It still is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

redraw this circuit as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhn3jA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can ignore resistance R3 from the circuit since there is a parallel non resistance path across it. Circuit is then simplified in to R1 // R2. That is 50 ohm resistance in parallel with 1A current source. Circuit is equivalent to 50V( 1A * 50ohm) with a series 50 Ohm resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ0aUC.png)</sup>

Comment: I agree with this. Once you've seen that it's R1 parallel to R2, the series resistance becomes 50 Ohms, and by Ohms law V = IR, giving 50V generated by the 1A source over a 50Ohm load.